# mySQL LOAD XML when parent and child have same tag name

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm pretty sure the answer is no here.. but wanted to just take a stab to see if anyone has a trick..
Not using any coding.. just using mySQL straight up.

My issue is that i can't get the parent and child values into a table, if they both have the same tag name.

sample xml:

```
   <parent id=456>
      <child id=123>
        <test>test</test>
      </child>
   </parent>
```

I have a simple table in mySQL like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tst_xml (
id varchar(100),
parent varchar(100), 
child varchar(100),
test varchar(100)
);
```

I have tried a few different tags in the LOAD XML statement.. but I simply can't get both id values into the table.. Since they expect the tag to be equal to the column name.. there doesn't seem to be a way to 'force' / 'hint' to the load that i want the parent node's value..

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/basicxml.txt'
    INTO TABLE tst_xml
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<child>';
```

As it is above, I can load the child's id value, and the 'test' element values. "parent" and "child" columns are left null of course.
So.... let me know if anyone has a trick, without using any code or changing the XML file..without even using multiple tables / LOAD XML statements.. (i know those options)
maybe some syntax trick, or some trick with using variables?  Again, just a shot in the dark.

Thanks!

[EDIT] same issue really, but slightly different angle on it..
Say I just want the **parent** value for id.
I use

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/basicxml.txt'
    INTO TABLE tst_xml
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<parent>';
```

but guess what? the values loaded into the id column in the table are that of the *child*.  And if I make even deeper nodes in the xml file, the load seems to just take the *last occurrence* of the id tag under the 'rows identified' level as the one to load into the table for that  tag record- no matter how much deeper it goes into that tag's children.

So I can't focus the load process at the level of the tag I provide in ROWS IDENTIFIED BY...  unless someone can help me with that??

Comment: *LOAD XML* loads only one level. If you specify `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<child>'` then only `child` level attributes (`id` and `test`) will be loaded.

Comment: actually, from what i read, and from what i've tested, you can load parent level attributes. the parent level ones repeat for each child. It works great.  However the issue is as mentioned - when they have the same name as a child one.